# Resource allocation algorithm for multiple users and multiple providers

Tags: resources, allocation

Suppose I have ***P*** providers, each of which can provide ***N*** resources. Also suppose we have ***U*** users and a function ***f*** which tells us the score of allocating a user ***u*** to a provider ***p***.

Now our objective is to pair a user with a provider which gives the maximum score (decided by ***f***) given a resource among the ***N*** resource is left. If not allocate it to the next best provider, or third best (if second best is also completely occupied) and so on. Note I am aware the solution will depend on the order in which one iterates over the user and is not a factor in our problem.

My question is, is there an efficient algorithm to do this?